# Python Indexerror: list index out of range while using index()

Tags: python, json, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    edit = []
    with open("wallet.json", "w") as file:
        for obj in file:
            dict = json.load(obj)
            edit.append(dict)

    userid = []
    for player in edit:
        userid.append(str(player["id"]))

    user = str(ctx.author.id)
    if userid.count(user) > 0:
        await ctx.reply("You already have an account")
    else:
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title = "Welcome to the Kingdoms of Sulphae!", description = "Sulphae is a place where people can grind for resources, conquer other factions, and become the greatest king to ever exist! Enjoy your stay!")
        embed.set_footer(text = "Made by Energia360, a really pog dude who decided to dedicate his summer break to making a Discord bot")
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        userid.append(user)

        edit[userid.index(user)]["id"] = user
        edit[userid.index(user)]["gold"] = 0
        edit[userid.index(user)]["fyre"] = 0
        edit[userid.index(user)]["faction"] = None

    json.dump(edit, file)
```

I have this piece of code here in Python for a Discord bot(I'm sure that doesn't matter much for this particular issue). The json file wallet.json is empty. This code gives me an Indexerror at

```
edit[userid.index(user)]["id"] = user
```

this part of my code.

```
    edit[userid.index(user)]["id"] = user
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the error message I got.

I'm not sure how the index() function could provide an Out of Range error. Solutions appreciated.

UPDATE: After adding a simple print() to see what `userid.index(user)` is, I got found out that it is 0. This didn't trigger any error, so using something in the json brackets may be the problem.

UPDATE 2: Moved `userid.index(user)` out of the brackets and made a variable to store it, didn't work. Maybe it's actually the "id" that's triggering the error.

Comment: If the `index` returns -1 it can cause trouble.

Comment: should I add a "print" command to see what index it returns?

Comment: Of course you should see the behavior of your code and perform fixes along the way.

Comment: No idea why, but got worse. Time to open Google :/
EDIT: Fixed, seems like json write mode isn't read mode but better lol
The stupid indexerror's still there tho

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve]. We don't know what "edit" or "wallet.json" are, so this is not *reproducible*.

Comment: sorry, wallet.json is an empty json file, edit is a list(it's initialized in the code)

Answer (score 0):

All users from `userid` came from `edit` at first. If the user is not in `userid`, it surely was not in `edit`.

When you *do not find* the user in `userid`, you append its id to `userid`, but not to `edit`. `userid` will be longer than `edit`. Not only that, since you appended the user to `userid`, it will be at the end of the list, an index that is guaranteed to not exist in `edit`. That's why you are getting an `IndexError`.

A solution would be to build the entire user object and append it to `edit`. Your code is a bit unclear and could be improved in other ways, but that would be the first step to making it not break.

Comment: I decided to append a new entry to ```edit``` instead of using ```userid```, and that didn't give me an Indexerror. However, an Attribute error popped up. I'm making a new thread for this, so thanks for helping me fix this!